# C - Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c, visual-studio, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm trying to read from .csv file in C using VS2019 and am getting Assertion Error.
Assertion error that I'm getting is _CrtIsValidHeapPointer which I believe is linked with memory leak but I'm unable to realize what's triggering it.

Any help would be appreciated.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct movie
{
    double score;
    char* title;
    int year;
    char* actors;
    char* genre;
};
```

And my function is:

```
void readMoviesFromCSV(movie* movies)
{
    FILE* inputFile;
    fopen_s(&inputFile, "Movies.csv", "r");

    if (inputFile == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inputFile);
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* lineBuffer = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 2048);
    char* current = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 512);

    fgets(lineBuffer, 2048, inputFile); // Discarding of the header

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMovies; i++)
    {
        fgets(lineBuffer, 2048, inputFile);

        current = strtok_s(lineBuffer, ",", &lineBuffer);
        (movies + i)->score = atof(current);

        current = strtok_s(lineBuffer, ",", &lineBuffer);
        strcpy_s((movies + i)->title, 512, current);

        current = strtok_s(lineBuffer, ",", &lineBuffer);
        (movies + i)->year = atoi(current);

        current = strtok_s(lineBuffer, ",", &lineBuffer);
        strcpy_s((movies + i)->actors, 512, current);

        current = strtok_s(lineBuffer, "\n", &lineBuffer);
        strcpy_s((movies + i)->genre, 512, current);

        printf("ID: %d\nScore: %.2lf\nTitle: %s\nYear: %d\nActors: %s\nGenre: %s\n\n", i + 1, (movies + i)->score, (movies + i)->title, (movies + i)->year, (movies + i)->actors, (movies + i)->genre);
    }

    free(lineBuffer);
    free(current);
    fclose(inputFile);
    return;
}
```

I allocated my movies array in main:

```
int main()
{
    movie* movies = (movie*)calloc(sizeof(movie), numberOfMovies);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMovies; i++)
    {
        (movies + i)->title = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 512);
        (movies + i)->actors = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 512);
        (movies + i)->genre = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 512);
    }

    readMoviesFromCSV(movies);
    // free(movies);
    return 0;
}
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: @user3121023 I fixed that, still did not resolve the issue.

When I comment out all free(); statements and fclose(); program does not give Assertion Failed but it does not return value, it' just gives sound and stops.

Comment: Well, strtok_s does change lineBuffer. After strtok_s is called, lineBuffer points to part of the string that is left after taking everything before the delimeter, "," in this case.

Answer (score 0):

At least this line is wrong:

```
movie* movies = (movie*)calloc(sizeof(movie), numberOfMovies);
```

The parameters are in wrong order. To fix, change it to:

```
movie* movies = (movie*)calloc( numberOfMovies, sizeof(movie) );
```

Comment: This is not the problem.